# helper search in codeigniter 2.1.4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I follow some tutorial and they use `search_highlight($text, $search_terms)` to highlight results.

And using: `$this->load->helper(array('search'));`

But i get the error like

`Unable to load the requested file: helpers/search_helper.php`

How can i use highlight function thanks

Comment: try $this->load->helper('search') to load helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in codeigniter helper called search_helper, so your tutorial probably wants you to create on.

In /helpers, create a file called search_helper.php & add your function there